# Migrar sistema moodle a otro servidor

Tags: moodle

Hola buenas tardes estoy realizando una migración de un sistema Moodle a un nuevo servidor pero tengo dudas. La documentación de Moodle dice que necesito únicamente 3 cosas la base da datos, moodledata y la aplicación moodle. La base de datos ya la importe en el nuevo servidor, según la documentación de migración Moodle, ahora debo de importar al directorio wwwroot (estoy utilizando Windows Server) la carpeta de moodledata la cual también ya coloqué en el nuevo servidor, ahora me dice que copie el código de la aplicación Moodle, pero no encuentro el código de la aplicación.
Estoy confundido ya que no se si deba de pasar las otras carpetas que se encuentran al mismo nivel de Moodle data.

Les comparto captura de pantalla de los directorios que se encuentran al mismo nivel de Moodle data.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Liga documentación que estoy siguiendo

https://docs.moodle.org/all/es/Migraci%C3%B3n_de_Moodle

Espero que me puedan apoyar.

Saludos y excelente martes.

Comment: Supongo que dentro de `htdocs`tienes todo el contenido (páginas públicas) de `moodle` y es precisamente eso a lo que se refieren con _código de la aplicación_

Comment: Si estas usando apache2 puedes encontrar la ruta del directorio del código de Moodle en unos de los archivos de configuración en `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`. Probablemente esté dentro de `/var/www` o `/var/www/html`.

Comment: La estructura de folders que has de encontrar en tu máquina la puedes ver aqui https://github.com/moodle/moodle

Answer (score -1):

Como bien dice la documentación necesitas migrar 3 cosas.

- Base de Datos - Se exporta en el formato de preferencia
- Moodledata - Se encuentra una carpeta antes que el código fuente de Moodle
- Moodle - La carpeta con el código fuente de moodle

Comment: El moodledata está justo en el directorio de la foto que compartiste